# Detect time pattern in sequence of events

Tags: time-series, clustering, unsupervised-learning, sequential-pattern-mining

I have a time series with a timestamp and an associated event:

| Time | Event |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | C |
| T | A |

I was wondering if there is a technique/method to figure out which events most often precede others in a given time window. I.e. 10 seconds before A happens B and C occur with 90% chance. Ideally the output should be the sequences that occur most often.

So far I have thought of using some sort of clustering, though a cluster would not suffice as I need to get the time direction right.

Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a very cool question! Clearly clustering won't work because of time dependent relationships, as you said. I came up with the following algorithm:

1. Have the time series data you have as a list
2. Instantiate an iterator, that will be another list/array that encompasses the time frame you have, e.g. 10 seconds would be an array of length 10, which includes 5 points at current point and 4 points after it
3. Count what events occur, hold them in a variable **if** they occur after/before your event of interest

Let me write a prototypical Python script:

```
### You can expand these variables depending on the types of events you have
number_of_events_b = 0
number_of_events_c = 0
### I take your data given as a variable time_series_data
for i in range(5, len(time_series_data) ):
    current = time_series_data[i)
    time_frame = time_series_data[i-5:i+4]
    ### If your event is A, count B and C 
    if current == "A":
        for j in time_frame:
            if j == "B":
                number_of_events_b += 1
            elif j == "C":
                number_of_events_c += 1

    ### If you want to get relative frequency of each you can simply do it based on 
    the counts, so I don't need to over complicate the answer
```

This code gives the result as what events precede or how they proceed with other events. If you want to get what **sequences** occur most often, that too is easy, you can just store events as a matrix. Like:

```
### Store the sequences as a matrix
sequences = []
### Again, I take your data given as a variable time_series_data
for i in range(5, len(time_series_data) ):
    current = time_series_data[i)
    time_frame = time_series_data[i-5:i+4]
    ### If your event is A, count B and C 
    if current == "A":
        sequences.append(time_frame)

### Now you should count to what extent each sequences occur
sequence_frequencies  = {} ### Store as a dict for later referral opportunity
for sequence in sequences:
    sequence_count = 0
    for other_seq in sequences:
       if sequence == other_seq:
           sequence_count += 1
    sequence_frequencies[sequence] = sequence_count
```

I believe then you can get which sequences occur most using dict methods, in python. I am a bit rusty on my coding and my process is often iterative, so if any syntax errors occur or the algorithm fall short, note that I just give a rough guideline.